# publicly access app from aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

I have just started with aws ec2.

I have deployed a simple web app on ec2 which listens on port 12345.

After SSH-ing into the instance from my windows machine using putty and once connected using curl for the apps endpoint and using either localhost, private IP address as well as public Dns (IPv4) it works fine.It does not work with IPv4 public ip though.

I now want to make that app accessible from the internet via browser. But, when I use public Dns or even Ipv4 Public ip along with the port , and try to access , it is not accessible. I only get the message , "This site can’t be reached" from chrome.

I have  Inbound rule setup for the security group associated with the instance, 
which allows ,
all trafic, via all protocol , via all ports (0-65535), and also I have given the Source as Custom, with IP range of 0.0.0.0/0.

I also have added another rule with same attributes, except for Source a Custom with IP range of , ::/0.

Can someone advise me on the right way to do this.

Comment: how to you getting the public ip of your instance ? did you check the box, assign public ip to this instance ?

Comment: also paste here your public ip and enable ICMP(ping) protocol for all the source ip, so that we can check.

Comment: as AmitK said there is simply not enough information here. How did you set up the EC2 instance? Are you using a dedicated or ElasticIP? If you can SSH and cannot find it with simple web access something is not set up correctly either in Inbound, Outbound or in your original setup, at least that is what it seems from your original description.